# Objective C Parse Query Results Using Two Classes Where Equals

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I currently have a Parse query in objective c that uses one class (Photo) to retrieve data.

```
PFQuery *photosFromUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"photo"];
[photosFromUsersQuery whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"type"];
[photosFromUsersQuery whereKeyExists:kESPhotoPictureKey];
[photosFromUsersQuery whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:sevenDaysAgo];

PFQuery *videosFromUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[videosFromUserQuery whereKeyExists:@"type"];
[videosFromUserQuery whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:sevenDaysAgo];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photosFromUsersQuery, videosFromUserQuery, nil]];

[query includeKey:kESPhotoUserKey];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

I now need to use a second class (user) which is a pointer in both classes.
I want to filter the data from the query above to only display data where the user has a Public profile.
In the user class, I have a column called privacy which either contains a value of Public or Private.

I have tried many approaches but none have worked.
Please help me accomplish this task.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the matchesQuery option. I don't do much objc, but it should look something like this.

```
PFQuery *photosFromUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"photo"];
[photosFromUsersQuery whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"type"];
[photosFromUsersQuery whereKeyExists:kESPhotoPictureKey];
[photosFromUsersQuery whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:sevenDaysAgo];

PFQuery *videosFromUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[videosFromUserQuery whereKeyExists:@"type"];
[videosFromUserQuery whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:sevenDaysAgo];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photosFromUsersQuery, videosFromUserQuery, nil]];

PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"]
[userQuery whereKey:@"privacy" equalTo:@"Public"]
[query whereKey:@kESPhotoUserKey matchesQuery: userQuery]
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

Comment: This returned zero results.